# Blogger To WordPress Permalink Redirection

Tags: permalinks, redirect, blogger

Is there any way to redirect following or anything permalink like this:

http://www.example.com/2014/02/post-title.html

to

http://www.example.com/2014/02/post-title/

Any link with a .html in the end to / in the end.

Comment: You could just keep the permalinks intact and not worry about it by adding .html to your permalinks. There are also a few plugins that can help with the transition https://www.google.com/search?q=blogger+to+wordpress+redirection

Comment: I know bout that, but I'm writing a tutorial about how to migrate & was wondering if there's any to make a redirection using .htaccess or functions.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up the redirection on the .htaccess file, adding this row:

```
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/(.+)\.html$ http://www.example.com/$1/? [R=301,L]
```